# Theming for React Native using react native ui kitten

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I am trying to use the react-native-ui-kitten for react native components and its working great. 
Lately I wanted to add theming in my app and to do that I used their 'RkTheme' and 'RkType' but none is working.

Expectation - setting the theme using RkTheme.setTheme(themeJson) should change the styling of elements already rendered on the screen

Actual - setting the theme using RkTheme.setTheme(themeJson) is not changing the style of the already rendered componenets.

Below is a part of package json

```
  "dependencies": {
"prop-types": "^15.6.1",
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.51.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
"react-native-popup-menu": "^0.9",
"react-native-ui-kitten": "3.1.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
"react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.11",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"realm": "^2.15.3",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"util": "^0.11.0",
```

},

Sample code for the react component

```
    import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button , TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {applyTheme} from '../config/bootstrap'
import {RkStyleSheet, RkTheme} from 'react-native-ui-kitten'
import { LightTheme } from '../config/lightTheme';
import { DarkTheme } from '../config/darkTheme';
export default class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.changeTheme = this.changeTheme.bind(this)
  }
  changeTheme(theme){
    if(theme){
      RkTheme.setTheme(DarkTheme,null)
    } else {
      RkTheme.setTheme(LightTheme,null)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Sample</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity  onPress = { (e) => this.changeTheme(false) }>
          <Text style={styles2.button1}>Apply Light</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity   onPress = { (e) => this.changeTheme(true) }>
          <Text style={styles2.button1}>Apply Dark</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})
const styles2 = RkStyleSheet.create(theme => ({
  button1 : {
    color : theme.colors.secondaryColor
  }
}))
```

Comment: What is the second parameter on your method `RkTheme.setTheme(DarkTheme,null)`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the 'setTheme' method in the library. It has only one parameter. I used both parameters because thats how they have done in one of their demo apps. RkTheme.setTheme(DarkTheme, null) and RkTheme.setTheme(DarkTheme) both are not working

Comment: I had a look at the .setTheme() and it does a merge of the existing theme and the new one. I don't know what the effect of that could be.

Comment: Had you come across their main docs? Your method should work as per  this doc

  [1]: https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/#/docs/quick-start/theme

Comment: In their demo app the link to which is available at https://github.com/akveo/kittenTricks/blob/master/README.md changing theme changes the styles of the components in real time. I tried using the same code posted in my question in their demo app and it was working just fine. It was changing the color of text of 'Apply Light' and 'Apply Dark'  as soon as i pressed them. The only difference i see in my and their code is that they are using expo react native sdk and I'm using react native from npm.

Comment: Okay I found out what i was doing wrong here. I wasn't using 'withRkTheme' for the 'Sample' in my stack navigator. Even so i am not able to see any changes when using connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRkTheme(Sample)) in my sample container as I am using redux.

Comment: Great you got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add 'withRkTheme' to the components that we suppose will change the theme colors in real time after changing theme. Also important point to note is that **if we are using any other custom components in the render function of the root component, the custom components should extend 'RkComponent' instead of 'React.Component'**. This Alone fixed my issue.